# Как убить неубиваемый процесс в Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, процесс

Как убить неубиваемый процесс? "Завершить процесс в ДЗ" - не идет;
стороннее ПО AnvirTaskManager - не помогает, командная строка через "taskkill /IM *.exe /F" также не спасает. Ума не приложу
ОС Win7

Comment: так он может убивается и быстро опять поднимается? Я такое видел с одним малюсеньким вирусом

Comment: посмотрите может служба повешена на этот процесс, и как только вы его убиваете служба его опять запускает.

Comment: systemexplorer бесплатный хорошо бьет блох в режиме администратора

Comment: Надо смотреть тот ли PID у него после убийства, что и до. А то, может, он и в самом деле поднимается заново.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если отбросить автоматически перезапускающиеся процессы, то да, действительно, в Windows иногда встречаются "неубиваемые" процессы. Он делятся на две группы. К первой относятся защищённые процессы, например, процессы антивируса, для "убийства" которых у пользователя не хватит прав и "зависшие", которые по каким-то причинам система "убить" не может. В моей практике встречались процессы из второй группы. Один раз так у меня завис отладчик `GDB`.

Для снятия таких зависших неубиваемых процессов можно использовать, например, Process Explorer Марка Руссиновича. Позволяет снять почти любой процесс. Но иногда не помогает. Тогда можно попробовать программу Process Hacker. В её арсенале целый набор методов для снятия процессов. Если не справился Process Explorer, часто помогает Process Hacker. Правой кнопкой мыши на требуемом процессе -> Miscellaneous -> Terminator. Также, если завис процесс какой-либо IDE в момент отладки, может помочь правой по отлаживаемому процессу Miscellaneous -> Detach from Debugger.

Однако, иногда встречается такая гадость, что её невозможно снять никаким методом. Почему это происходит, мне неизвестно. Но пару раз встречалось. И не всегда при этом машина способна нормально уйти в перезагрузку, иной раз этот зависший процесс не даёт этого сделать. И тогда помогает только кнопка Reset.

Answer (score 1):

А если попробовать программой unlocker ?

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу. Вы можете оставлять любое количество комментариев под своим сообщением. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/44519)

Comment: @metalurgus, вроде является.

Comment: @Qwertiy каждый должен скачать прогу и проверить - а вдруг она файлы анлочит, а не процессы убивает

Comment: @PashaPash, процессы убивать она тоже умеет - те, которые блокируют.

Comment: @korytoff, ты где в ответе ссылку нашёл? o_O

Comment: @Qwertiy это SO сам коммент добавляет при проверке ответа на корректность. Просто там нету варианта про недостаточно расширенный ответ. Надо бы наверно на мету добавить вопрос

Comment: Ребята, всем спасибо! Проблема решена! Почему-то снес Аваст к чертям, и все стало ок.
п.с. Unlocker тоже не помогал