# Можно ли принудительно отобрать используемый файл?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Есть файл, который может использоваться чем угодно.
Возможно ли найти все процессы, которые используют этот файл и отрубить, что бы затем принудительно удалить его?

Comment: Можно. Но вам понадобятся нестандартные права, чтобы убить процесс, бегущий не под вашей учёткой. А ещё если этот процесс висит где-нибудь в вызове в режиме ядра, может быть проблематично. Вот по теме: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/469392/10105

Comment: То есть найти по идее можно, а вот с «отрубить» могут быть проблемы.

Comment: @VladD, а если я админ на сервере, то какие могу возникнуть проблемы, если процесс не системный?

Comment: Если вы админ на сервере, тут проблем меньше, т. к. права у вас есть. Но снова-таки, если процесс висит в системном вызове, который не возвращается, то вы его не убьёте пока он таки не вернётся. Например, приложение пытается читать сетевой диск, и висит в ядре до прихода таймаута по соединению. Если вы погуглите «неубиваемый процесс», там много есть всякого.

Comment: Если речь идёт об администрировании, может быть проще не писать самому, а использовать [утилиту Handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) и/или Process Explorer оттуда же ([вот про него с картинками](http://superuser.com/a/399660)).

Comment: Возможно. Но, возможно, проще будет использовать широкоизвестный Unlocker любой версии.